# Help with ER design

Tags: mysql, database-design, subtypes

So i am trying to create a db for a restaurant as a homework assignment.. However there is a spot that confuses me and involves the dish entity.

> "Every dish must belong to a category (soup,appetizer,salad,main
>   dish). The main dish must be either pasta,pizza or rice"

The problem is that pizza and pasta have unique attributes... So the question is do I encompass all of them with the rest of the dish attributes and nullify them when the dish is not pizza or pasta? Or do I form some kind of ISA entities? And in the second case, won't it complicate my db a lot by adding many entities?

Comment: There are a number of similar questions on DBA: basically "should I create a zillion columns even though some records won't need them all" or "should I abandon traditional database design and use a key-value store"?  Most of the time, columns are the better answer.  NULLs don't require much space to store, and the alternatives (parsing comma-separated values or XML, joining multiple attribute records) tend to perform very poorly.

Comment: key-value stores do not scale.  The SELECTs you need to write are ugly.  Etc, etc.  I prefer to put the miscellany info in JSON in a TEXT column, meanwhile keeping only the important (for searching / ordering) columns visible to MySQL.  And there are limits on "zillion" -- under 1K columns, under 8KB bytes (with exceptions).